# How to pronounce this sloka?

Tags: scripture, shloka, translation, source

I found this sloka online and I think there are some misspellings or mistakes in this version:

> *Pathaya vaa patale , Sthapaya vaa sakala Bhuvana samraye |*
> *Matha thava pada yugalam , munchami naiva munchami ||*

Can someone please tell me what the original sloka is, its origin, and how to pronounce it? (Or share a video of someone reciting it?)

([Here](https://www.hindupedia.com/en/Slokas_for_solving_various_problems) is the link to the place where I found it, Hindupedia.com- it's the thirty-first sloka)

Comment: To translate Sanskrit correctly we need to know the context, so please link whichever site/source you read that shloka from.

Answer (score 1):

*(Scroll to the bottom for the transcription)*

The [Hindupedia](https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/4/18/12?d=1) article also includes the source,

> These slokas and the method of chanting them have been taken from a book “Stotra Chinthamani” Compiled by Sri Vathsa Somadeva Sarma and published in Tamil by Surabhi Jagatguru Sathabdhi publications, Madras

(This means that the slokas were originally published in Tamil. If you wish to, and if you speak Tamil, you can buy it online [here](https://www.srisurabhibook.com/product/sri-stothra-chainthamani/). Tamil is a phonetic language, so if you get the book it should help you to find the exact pronunciation.)

That said, though, here is a broken-down version of the sloka. I did this by translating it bit by bit from Sanskrit, so this should be a fairly decent approximation.

> Pathaya vaa Patale, Sthapaya Vaa Sakala Bhuvana Samraye,
>
> Matha Thava Pada Yugalam, Munchami Naiva Munchami.

Translation, again courtesy of Hindupedia,

> Push me in to Patala or establish me as the king of the universe,
>
> Oh Mother , I would not leave your two feet, will not leave.

| "word" | meaning | phonetic | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "pathaya" | literally to send, likely extrapolated to 'to push' by the translator | pāṭhāya | ([Source](https://prabhupadabooks.com/cc/adi/16/18?d=1)) |
| "vaa" | can mean variously 'either,' 'or,' 'and,' 'also,' etc. In this case it likely means 'or' | vā | ([Source](https://sanskritdictionary.org/pathaya?sd_query=va)) |
| "patale" | form of *Patala*, or the under/netherworld | pāṭale | (Source) |
| "sthapaya" | meaning establish, established | sthāpaya | ([Source](https://prabhupadabooks.com/cc/madhya/9/44?d=1)) |
| "sakala" | meaning all, everything | sakala | ([Source](https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/4/31/20?d=1)) |
| "bhuvana" | meaning, earth, universe, world | bhuvana | ([Source](https://prabhupadabooks.com/cc/adi/6/94?d=1)) |
| "samraye" | possible variant of Sanskrit sāmrājya, meaning king, empire, power | sāmrāye | ([Source](https://s%C4%81mr%C4%81jya)) |

| "word" | meaning | phonetic | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "matha" | meaning mother | mātā | ([Source](https://prabhupadabooks.com/bg/9/17?d=1)) |
| "tava" | meaning 'your' | tava | ([Source](https://prabhupadabooks.com/bg/1/3?d=1)) |
| "pada yugalam" | compound word, actually *pāda-yugalam*, means feet, or both the feet | pāda-yugalam | ([Source](https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/4/26/20?d=1)) |
| "munchami" | likely from Sanskrit root *मुञ्च*, or *manch*, meaning release, discharge, let go, conjugated to munchami | munchāmi | ([Source](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%9A%E0%A5%8D#Sanskrit)) |
| "naiva" | meaning never, not at all; contracted form of 'na eva' (not ever) | naiva | ([Source](https://www.learnsanskrit.cc/translate?search=naiva&dir=au)) |

Put together, this gives you:

> pāṭhāya vā pāṭale, sthāpaya sakala sāmrāye;
>
> mātā tava pāda-yugalam, munchāmi naiva munchāmi

(Note that there is a bit of a rhyme between pāṭhāya and sthāpaya; pāṭale and sāmrāye)

Comment: Good detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Going by that Hindupedia link in the other answer, which is where the asker's english verse originated, here is the correct verse, in Hindi and Telugu (the only Indian two languages I learnt, so if you speak other language perhaps you can copy this and paste in google translate, just FYI):

This verse is entirely Sanskrit (not Tamil etc., but we know Tamil and other langauges descended from Sanskrit, so would not be surprised if the verse is identical in Tamil or Telugu or Bengali also):

**पथया वा पाताले सथपया वा सकल भुवन साम्राये,
माता तव पादयुगलम मुञ्चामी नैव मुञ्चामी!**

**పథయా వా పాతాళే స్థాపయా వా సకల భువన సాంరాజ్యే,
మాతా తవ పాదయుగళం ముఞ్చామి నైవ ముఞ్చామి**

The other answer incorrectly says the first word is pAthAya, which is not the right word here. Because it is formed from 'pata'+'Aya', the suffix 'Aya' is a 4th vibhakti for the first-person-case indicating the 'for/to' case. pAtAya means I go or I went, but here we are saying the Goddess can send us (instead of 'I will go'). Secondly,  the 2nd word 'pAtAla' shows additional context here. So going by the full context here, the first word has to mean 'send to' or 'throw down' i.e. a down-fall, or falling into, or being thrown down (pAtAla is the netherworld under earth, sotospeak). The correct first word has to come from Sanskrit root/dhAtu - 'patha' meaning throw [link here](https://wiki.yoga-vidya.de/Sanskrit_Verbal_Roots_List_with_English_Translation#P_-_List_of_Sanskrit_Verbal_Roots_beginning_with_letter_p):

[image]

Because this verse is addressed to the Goddess, the first word has to be pathyA. Similar with sthapayA.

Thus, its correct meaning is - *Throw/send me to Patala or establish me as the king of the universe. Oh Mother, I would still not leave your two feet, will not leave them.*